# Modifying Camera Solver keyframes

Tags: camera, keyframes, tracking

So I'm quite new to Blender, but have 15+ years with 3DS Max... so apologies if this is a basic error

I've tracked a drone shot and set up a 3D scene in Blender.

It seems to work OK, but the camera path (which seems to be dictated by a Camera Solver constraint) is a bit jumpy, and in a few instances jumps miles away from the scene.

I can see individual points on the track path but can't select or edit them, and no keyframe info appears in the timeline.

Do I need to bake the animation in there somehow?

I was hoping to be able to move/delete some of the camera path points as one could do in 3DS Max

Any help hugely appreciated

---

I'm off the tracking workspace now, as I've tracked and solved the camera movement. (Although in that graph editor I wasbt able to edit the movement of track points, only select and delete the whole track)

I've set up a 3D modelling scene now, and aligned the points to correct scale and X/Y/plane orientation.

It's the actual path of the solved camera that's the issue, as there are four points of the 300-or-so key frames that are way off, so the path has four random displacements during the movement.

I can select the camera itself, and the path points are visible, but I can't see any key frames related to the camera movement, and the path points can't be selected individually to refine the camera path.

Comment: Are you in the Motion Tracking workspace? You should be able to edit the location of individual tracks on a frame by frame basis with that workspace open as well as editing the graph with each track point and the key frames for each one as well. [This is what I mean](https://imgur.com/a/tyhDLN1)

Answer (score 0):

You can press <kbd>F3</kbd> > *Bake Action* (*Object > Animation > Bake Action...*) and in the popup window just make sure *Visual Keying and Clear Constraints* is checked as well as ensuring *Bake Data* is set to *Object*.
Press Ok and it should have baked the camera solver to keyframes.